# Area calculation with four input fields using Jquery to convert Ropani-Anna to sq.ft

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four input fields.I want to convert ropani ,anna, paisa and dam to sq. ft. I'm unable to convert it .I want to calculate value of four input fields and want to display in another field. Please help me.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".ropani", function() {
      var area = 0;
      $(‘.ropani’).on(‘keyup’, function() {
            var ropani = $(".ropani").val();
            var aana = $(".aana").val();
            var paisa = $(".paisa").val();
            var dam = $(".dam").val();
            area += ropani * 5476.0000;
            area += aana * 342.2500;
            area += paisa * 85.5625;
            // if (parseFloat(daam) < 4) {
            area += daam * 21.390625;
            //s }

            $(“.total”).html(area);
          };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type=”text” class=”ropani” />
<input type=”text” class=”anna” />
<input type=”text” class=”paisa” />
<input type=”text” class=”dam” />
<input type=”text” class=”total” />
```

Comment: Explain the specific problem and errors encountered. Provide sample input with expected results. Also explain what those multipliers represent. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: For a start, it seems you are using the wrong text editor, or wrong settings in it: the characters `“` and `”` should all be `"`, and the `‘` and `’` should be `'`. This causes the classes in HTML to be wrong, and syntax errors in the Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few mistakes in the code. Assuming that you want the value in the fifth field on change of any field, please consider the following:

```js
$('input:not(.total)').on('keyup', function() {
  var area = 0;
  var ropani = $(".ropani").val();
  var aana = $(".aana").val();
  var paisa = $(".paisa").val();
  var daam = $(".dam").val();
  area += ropani * 5476.0000;
  area += aana * 342.2500;
  area += paisa * 85.5625;
  // if (parseFloat(daam) < 4) {
  area += daam * 21.390625;
  //s }

  $(".total").val(parseFloat(area));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
ropani<input type="text" class="ropani" /><br> anna
<input type="text" class="aana" /><br> paisa
<input type="text" class="paisa" /><br> dam
<input type="text" class="dam" /><br> total
<input type="text" class="total" /><br>
```

---

Changes after [@Fallerreaper's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1404049/fallenreaper) suggestions:

```js
var obj = {};
$('input:not(.total)').on('keyup', function(event) {
  var area = 0;
  if (parseFloat(event.target.value) == NaN) return;
  obj[event.target.classList[0]] = event.target.value;
  obj.ropani = obj.ropani ? obj.ropani : $(".ropani").val();
  obj.aana = obj.aana ? obj.aana : $(".aana").val();
  obj.paisa = obj.paisa ? obj.paisa : $(".paisa").val();
  obj.daam = obj.daam ? obj.daam : $(".dam").val();
  area += obj.ropani * 5476.0000 + obj.aana * 342.2500 + obj.paisa * 85.5625 + obj.daam * 21.390625;

  $(".total").val(parseFloat(area));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
ropani<input type="text" class="ropani" /><br> anna
<input type="text" class="aana" /><br> paisa
<input type="text" class="paisa" /><br> dam
<input type="text" class="dam" /><br> total
<input type="text" class="total" /><br>
```

Comment: if you can, you can also save computation a bit by defining static references to the ropani, aana, paisa, and daam.  Therefore, you dont need to query the dom for it every time.

Comment: @Fallenreaper thank you kind sir, I'll make the changes!

Comment: I had a issue. Can I ask you @ Fallenreaper

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `change` event to the `input.ropani`. Add `keyup` event to the all `inputs` except `.total`. use `.val()` to change the value of `input`.

```js
$("input:not(.total)").on("keyup", function() {
  var area = 0;
  var ropani = +$(".ropani").val() || 0;
  var aana = +$(".aana").val() || 0;
  var paisa = +$(".paisa").val() || 0;
  var dam = +$(".dam").val() || 0;
  area += ropani * 5476.0000;
  area += aana * 342.2500;
  area += paisa * 85.5625;
  area += dam * 21.390625;
  console.log(area); 
  $('.total').val(area);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="ropani" />
<input type="number" class="anna" />
<input type="number" class="paisa" />
<input type="number" class="dam" />
<input type="number" class="total" />
```

Comment: There is an error in the OP's code you didn't correct: `anna` != `aana`