# Unable to fill the other fields on the basis of option selected

Tags: javascript, php

I want to fill the other fields on the form from database on the basis of option selected, but unable to do using php and javascript.I have attached json data I received in question. I want to fill other form fields when i select option from the form field houseowner_select and i want to show div app_houseowner when i select  option from the select box having id applicant_is.

```js
$("#applicant_id").on("change", function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  makeAjaxRequest1(selected);
});

function makeAjaxRequest1(opts) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      opts: opts
    },
    url: "get_houseownerinfo_applicant.php",
    success: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      debugger;

      $("#applicant_wardno").val(res.ho_wardno);
      $("#applicant_citizenship_no").val(res.ho_citizenship_number);
      $("#applicant_phone").val(res.ho_phone);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<select name="applicant_is" class="form-control" ng-model="applicant.applicant_is" ng-change="callback_change_applicant_is($event)">
  <option value="">--select--</option>
  <option value="app_houseowner">घरधनी</option>
  <option value="landowner">जग्गाधनी</option>
  <option value="waris">वारिश</option>
</select>
<div class="app_houseowner">
  <select class="form-control" name="houseowner_select" id="applicant_id">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="<?php if (isset($row11['id'])){ echo $row11['id'];}?>">
      <?php if (isset($row11['ho_name_en'])){ echo $row11['ho_name_en'];}?>
    </option>

  </select>
</div>
<input type="text" name="applicant_phone" class="form-control" id="applicant_phone">
<select name="applicant_wardno" class="form-control" id="applicant_wardno">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= 19; $x++) {
       echo "<option value=".$x.">".$x."</option>";
    }?>
</select>
<input type="text" name="applicant_citizenship_no" class="form-control" id="applicant_citizenship_no">
```

[image]

Comment: Did you get the expected result in `console.log(res);` from the ajax call ?

Comment: There is no elements with id `applicant_salutation` in the shown HTML

Comment: Also  there is no element with id applicant_district in the shown HTML

Comment: @prabinashrestha you might want to add the ajax response as text

Comment: Yes , I got the expected result from the console.log(res) and I want to show this in other fields. I didn't put all the fields in the question but it is already in my form. @Cid

Comment: It doesnot  matter , which method i used , but i want to display in other fields. Please help me@shrys

Comment: I removed the fields  in the  question only but there is already in my form and i removed in the question as well@Priyank

Comment: @prabinashrestha still you got any error ? If yes then what ?

Comment: No error. But fields are not filled with the data. Can you look it through any other media?@Priyank

Comment: console.log(res.ho_wardno) or alert(res.ho_wardno) and check did you get the value of res.ho_wardno

Comment: I got undefined error. @Priyank

Comment: Same code was working before 2 days.@Priyank

Comment: that means  you didn't get the value from the json. Check your json response first

Comment: When i did console.log(res), I got json value as above.@Priyank

Comment: All the in the form fields are correct still i'm unable to fill the form fields with values.@Priyank

Comment: add dataType: 'json', in your ajax request  and check, also console.log(res) and give me the response i will check and update you asap

Comment: Thank you so much @Priyank. It works. But why it was not working?

Comment: Can I ask you other question if I stuck in a problem?@Priyank

Comment: When you make ajax request with jason data you have to add data type because of that it's not working and don't forgot to upvote my answer..:)

Comment: Yes you can if i am free i will definitely help you

Comment: Mistakenly it came like that. You save my day @Priyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove or comment `$("#applicant_salutation").val(res.ho_salutation)` and `$("#applicant_district").val(res.ho_citizenship_district)` line in from your javascript code bcoz both id is not available in your html.

> **Also add dataType: 'json' in you ajax request**

As i have checked `applicant_wardno` is select box and you have to set selected for displaying value in the select box instead of setting val.

[check this link for setting selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140862/how-to-select-a-value-in-dropdown-javascript)

Comment: I need your help.@Priyank

Comment: @Prabina,Please let me know what you need from my side

Comment: I will try again and if I couldnot do , I will post a question  and tag you the link. @Priyank

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572297/unable-to-get-login-user-information-in-multiple-php-pages @Priyank

Answer (score 0):

You can debbug with an alert: `alert(res.ho_wardno);` and see if the value is being returned from the ajax query;

```
      $("#applicant_wardno").val(res.ho_wardno);
      alert(res.ho_wardno);
      $("#applicant_citizenship_no").val(res.ho_citizenship_number);
      $("#applicant_phone").val(res.ho_phone);
```

Comment: I need your help . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57619673/unable-to-dynamically-add-multiple-input-fields-and-submit-to-database-with-java @shrys