# Unable to dynamically add multiple input fields and submit to database with javascript and php and change submit button value on submit button click

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically add multiple input fields and submit to database with javascript and php and change submit button value on submit button click. It works when i didn't dynamically add forms. When I click add button to dynamically add more input fields, the subit button value changes to saved. I want make it to change value of submit button after data is inserted to database.

Please help me.

html code

```
  <div id="dataRows" >
 <div class="fieldRow" id="template">
  <form id="charkilla">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" name='reg_id'>
 <select name="ch_direction[]" class="form-control" ng-model="ch.ch_direction" required>
 <option value="n">उत्तर</option>
<option value="e">पुर्व</option>
<option value="s">दक्षिण</option>
 <option selected="selected" value="w">पश्चिम</option>
</select>                                            
 <input type="text" name="ch_actual_setback[]" class="ch_actual_setback" id="ch_actual_setback">
 <input type="text" class=" form-control" name="ch_standard_setback[]" id="ch_standard_setback" placeholder=" ">
 <input type="submit" id="btnAdd" value="add" style="height:40px;width:70px" class="button add btn btn-primary">

 <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit" style="height:40px;width:80px"/>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>

      $(function () {
            jQuery(document).on("ready", function () {
                initAddRows();
            });
            function initAddRows() {
                var template = jQuery("#template"),
                    dataRows = jQuery("#dataRows");
                jQuery("#btnAdd").on("click", function () {      
                    var newRow = '<div class="med_box"><div class="col-sm-3">\n' +
                        '                                <div class="form-group fg-float">\n' +
                        '                                    <div class="fg-line">\n' +
                        '                                       <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail2">ch_direction</label> <select name="ch_direction[]"
                        '   class="form-control" ng-model="ch.ch_direction" required> <option value="n">उत्तर</option>\n' +
                        ' <option value="e">पुर्व</option><option value="s">दक्षिण</option></select>

                                            <br>\n' +
                        '                                           \n' +
                        '                                    </div>\n' +

                        '\n' +
                        '                            <div class="col-sm-2">\n' +
                        '                                <div class="form-group fg-float">\n' +
                        '                                    <div class="fg-line">\n' +
                        '                                        <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail2">ch_actual_setback *</label> <input type="text" name="ch_actual_setback[]" class="ch_actual_setback" id="ch_actual_setback">  <input type="hidden" name="frequency_id[]" class="frequency_id"> <br>\n' +
                        '                                            \n' +
                        '                                    </div>\n' +
                        '                               \n' +
                        '                                </div>\n' +
                        '                            </div>\n' +
                        '\n' + 
                        '                            <div class="col-sm-2">\n' +
                        '                                <div class="form-group fg-float">\n' +
                        '                                    <div class="fg-line">\n' +
                        '                                        <label class="" for="exampleInputEmail2">ch_standard_setback *</label> <input type="text" name="ch_standard_setback[]" class="ch_standard_setback" id="ch_standard_setback">\n' +
                        '                                    </div>\n' +
                        '                                   \n' +
                        '                                </div>\n' +
                        '                            </div>\n' +

                        '                           <br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp  <button class="button remove btn btn-primary" id="btnDel" type="button">Remove</button>\n' + '<div class="clearfix clear"></div></div>';
                    fieldRows = dataRows.find(".med_box");
                    fieldRows.filter(":last").after(newRow);            

                });  
                dataRows.on("click", ".remove", function () {
                    jQuery(this).parent().remove();
                });
            }
        });
``
js
```

````
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#charkilla').submit(function(event){
                     setTimeout(function(){
              $('.submitBtn').attr('value','OK');
          }, 3000);
          var stuff = $('#charkilla').serialize();
          jQuery.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'charkilla.php',
              data:{ stuff:stuff },
              dataType: "JSON",
              success: function( response ){
                console.log(res);debugger;
                var res = JSON.stringify(response);
                if(res.reg_id != 0) {
                  window.location = 'registration_detail.php?success='+ res.msg +'&id=' + res.reg_id;
                } else {
                  window.location = 'registration_detail.php?success='+ res.msg;
                }
              }
          });

          //Prevents form submission
          return false;
      });
    });

```

charkilla.php
```
 <?php
 require_once "conn.php"; 
$ch_direction= $ch_actual_setback=$ch_standard_setback=$reg_id="";
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){ 
 $temp = explode('&', $_POST['stuff']);
  $keys = array_keys($temp);
  for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++) {
    $afterstr = substr($temp[$i], strpos($temp[$i], '=') + 1);
    $temp[strstr($temp[$i],'=',true)] = $afterstr;
    unset($temp[$i]);
  }
  $t = extract($temp);
     mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
         $sql = "INSERT INTO bps_registration_charkilla (ch_direction, ch_actual_setback,ch_standard_setback,reg_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
  if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss",$ch_direction, $ch_actual_setback,  $ch_standard_setback, $reg_id);
$reg_id=intval($_POST['reg_id']);
$ch_direction=$ch_direction; 
 $ch_actual_setback = $ch_actual_setback;
$ch_standard_setback= $ch_standard_setback;        
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
      if(!empty($reg_id)){
        $data['msg'] = "Submitted form successfully .";
        $data['reg_id'] = $reg_id;
      } else {
        $data['msg'] = "Form submission could not be completed, please try again!";
        $data['reg_id'] = 0;
      }
    } else {
      $data['msg'] = "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
      $data['reg_id'] = 0;
    }
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
````

Comment: what exactly you want, not clear!

Comment: You helped me to solve before one problem. In the same code when I click submit button , the value of submit button chnaged from submit ok. But in this example I want to add more dynamic form fields when I click add button and when i submit the form the value of submit button should be changed. @Pathik Vejani

Comment: But in this form , when I click add button to add dynamic form fields ,the value  of submit button changed to ok @Pathik Vejani

Comment: @Prabina You trying to `console.log(res);debugger;` without having this `var res` available yet, recommend to to move this line of code below the `var res = JSON.stringify(response);`, also move this line of code below `console.log(res)` : `$('.submitBtn').attr('value','Saved');`

Comment: you have used `setTimeout`, so after 3 seconds button value will be changed.

Comment: also, I can't see `btnAdd` to add row. Where is `add more` button?

Comment: I removed console.log(res);debugger;  without having this var res @Serghei Leonenco

Comment: @Prabina Have you tried?

Comment: Sorry mistakenly I removed add button in question while editing question. I have added. @Pathik Vejani

Comment: @Prabina where and what you want to add data on click on btnAdd? You are calling function `initAddRows` here `jQuery(document).on("ready", function () { initAddRows();});` on page load, which is wrong

Comment: The form is being added when i clicked add button. @Pathik Vejani

Comment: yes the form is being added. When i clicked add button the value of submit button changed but i want to changed submit button value when i click submit button. I changed the method now. @Pathik Vejani